# Creating static Windows.Forms.Control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project to which I delegate the function of creating a library of (static)? classes used in all my other projects. It is referenced via solution in these cases.

For instance, I have an extension which creates checkboxes within a given GroupBox's panel, and that works great:

```
public static void PreencheCheckboxesPanel(this Panel p, List<CheckBox> listaCheckBoxs) {
    var count = 0;
    listaCheckBoxs.ForEach(
        i => {
            i.Location = new Point(10, 10 + ((count) * 25)); //"dynamic" and not-so-effective resizing here
            i.AutoSize = true;
            count++;
        });
    p.Controls.AddRange(listaCheckBoxs.ToArray());
}}
```

Problem is, I need to insert a static checkbox on the top of the list, which will receive a method to (un)?check all the checkboxes below. 
So my code will become

```
internal static CheckBox CKB_ancora = new CheckBox(){};
public static void PreencheCheckboxesPanel(this Panel p, List<CheckBox> listaCheckBoxs) {
    var count = 0;
    if (adicionaAncora) {
        CKB_ancora.Text = textoAncora;
        CKB_ancora.CheckedChanged += (sender, args) => {
            ChecaCheckBoxes(p, CKB_ancora.Checked);
        };
        listaCheckBoxs.Insert(0, CKB_ancora);
    }
    listaCheckBoxs.ForEach(
        i => {
            i.Location = new Point(10, 10 + ((count) * 25)); //"dynamic" and not-so-effective resizing here
            i.AutoSize = true;
            count++;
        });
    p.Controls.AddRange(listaCheckBoxs.ToArray());
}}
```

where `ChecaCheckBoxes` is another

```
public static void ChecaCheckBoxes(this Panel b, bool checkStatus = true) {
    var listaCheckBoxs = (from Control c in b.Controls where c is CheckBox select (CheckBox)c).ToList();
    listaCheckBoxs.ForEach(
        i => {
            i.Checked = checkStatus;
        });
}
```

and `CKB_ancora` needs to be a **solution-wide recognized** object.

The reason? I have another extension named `GetSelectedCheckBoxes` which will be used to return all the checked ... ah... checkboxes within the groupbox. And, in order to make sure that the "anchor" (I call it like this, since I don't have a name to a (un)?check-all checkbox) won't be returned as well.

If I run this code, it will compile, but... will run accross an InvalidOperationException at Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault, right at Main(); Apparently, a control cannot be created/instantied before this method is run at mainpoint, *which is the exact definition of "static"*.

Question: Knowing that I NEED a way to keep this particular check solution-wide visible... How do I do it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but one possible suggestion: The check box controls that you want to be able to access solution-wide don't need to be static themselves, you just need a static reference somewhere to them. Maybe a static class containing a static reference to a List<> containing references to these special checkboxes?

Comment: @RenniePet Thanks for the suggestion... but since it is static, it will be compiled (and instantiated) when the program starts running. The pre-requisite for SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault is that no controls are created _before_ it. And will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have not provided [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and lacking enough context it is very hard to provide good, specific advice.

That said, it seems that somewhere in this static class of yours, you have a field named `CKB_ancora`, and you are probably initializing it using a field initializer, possibly like this:

```
private CheckBox CKB_ancora = new Checkbox();
```

And having done this, you are finding that when the class is initialized (typically on the first time something in the class is accessed at runtime), that happens too soon and an exception is thrown.

Assuming that's correct, then it seems to me that most obvious and simplest "fix" is to initialize the object lazily. For example:

```
private Lazy<CheckBox> _ckb_ancora =
    new Lazy<CheckBox>(() => new CheckBox());

private CheckBox CKB_ancora { get { return _ckb_ancora.Value; } }
```

That will wrap the object storage in a property, which in turn uses an instance of `Lazy<T>` to defer initialization until the first time any code actually tries to access it.

Now, that said, I'm not very enamored of your approach here, with a static member that is used in some instantiated object. What if someone using your library wants to use the code with two or more `Panel` instances? A `Control` (including a `CheckBox`) can't be a child of more than one other `Control` at a time, so having a single static instance of the `Control` is just not going to work.

IMHO, it would probably be better to instead use some identifying feature such as the `Name` or `Tag` property of the `CheckBox` to handle the control appropriately (e.g. such as filtering it out of enumerations).

For example:

```
public static void PreencheCheckboxesPanel(this Panel p, List<CheckBox> listaCheckBoxs) {
    var count = 0;
    if (adicionaAncora) {
        CheckBox CKB_ancora = new CheckBox();

        CKB_ancora.Text = textoAncora;
        CKB_ancora.Name = "CKB_ancora";
        CKB_ancora.CheckedChanged += (sender, args) => {
            ChecaCheckBoxes(p, CKB_ancora.Checked);
        };
        listaCheckBoxs.Insert(0, CKB_ancora);
    }
    listaCheckBoxs.ForEach(
        i => {
            i.Location = new Point(10, 10 + ((count) * 25)); //"dynamic" and not-so-effective resizing here
            i.AutoSize = true;
            count++;
        });
    p.Controls.AddRange(listaCheckBoxs.ToArray());
}}
```

And, for example:

```
public static void ChecaCheckBoxes(this Panel b, bool checkStatus = true) {
    var listaCheckBoxs = b.Controls
        .OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Name != "CKB_ancora").ToList();

    listaCheckBoxs.ForEach(
        i => {
            i.Checked = checkStatus;
        });
}
```

That way, when you go to retrieve the list of `CheckBox` controls, the special one you added at the beginning is ignored.

Even with that, I think the code is still pretty fragile. The above would work better, but IMHO it would probably be even better if you weren't using static members for all of this in the first place. I.e. instead you should design some mechanism that allows you to relate an *instance* of the helper class to the `Panel` object it's helping with, so that you can in fact initialize and store per-instance information, without running into problems of order of execution, as well as of limitations of use of the code with just a single client.

Without a better code example, I don't see any good way to offer any *specific* advice along those lines though.

Comment: My bad. I seriously thought I made a good point up there. And, actually, you nailed it! I was trying to find a way to use the aforementioned `CKB_ancora` as comparable object.
Indeed, the usage of static objects is far from recommended for this purpose. I just didn't find any kinds of uniquely-identifiable properties I could use, such as html's ID.
As for the single-client fragility... Multiple panels would __not__ countain that checkbox (it would not be within either ControlCollection) _ever_, since I only use it to compare, so it will (_should_) be safe to use with multiples.

Comment: +1 for the Lazy implementation, thought. I will try it out and accept your answer if it fits my purposes. 
Any recommendations to improve my question will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Re: question improvements: in addition to the MCVE link I offered above, you may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In terms of specific aspects of your question, I'll just give a couple of examples: is the assignment of the `Location` and `AutoSize` properties _critical_ to demonstrating what your need is? I doubt it, and if not those statements should have been left out. At the same time, where is the declaration of `CKB_ancora`? That particular members seems central to your question, yet you left out that important detail. Those links offer advice in more detail.

Comment: I do read this link. I always do. And I kept it in mind while writing this post.
While I agree that CKB_ancora should be defined in it (I DID forget about it, sorry), `Location` and `AutoSize` are important for that particular method.  Without it, more questions would be raised regarding it`s functionality (... _I know_, I'm not trying to sell it).